# Tilde (~/) not working on if then statement in Shell script

Tags: shell, file, home-directory, tilde-expansion

I have the following script

```
file=${file:-letsdump.sh}    
checkfile="~/mysql_backup/$file"
if [ -e "$checkfile" ]; then
mv ~/mysql_backup/$file ~/mysql_backup/$file-bak-$(date +%d%m%Y_%H%M).bak
else
echo 'file doesnt exist'   
fi
```

I know my file is there, I am thinking it could be something to do with the ~/ ?

It never finds the file

Comment: Inside quotes, the `~` isn't expanded.

Comment: by the way, this is rather a FAQ.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Double quotes (really, any quotes) prevent `~` from being expanded. Use instead:

```
checkfile=~/mysql_backup/"$file"
```

...or, even better, use `$HOME` in all scripts, and consider `~` to be a facility for interactive/human use only.

Comment: YES! Home worked perfect!

Answer (score 2):

The `~` character is not expanded inside double-quoted strings.

In this context, `~` is equivalent to `$HOME`, which *is* expanded in double-quoted strings, so you could write:

```
checkfile="$HOME/mysql_backup/$file"
```

When followed by a user name, `~` refers to that user's home directory, which is not tracked by any environment variable; `"~fred/"` would not expand, but writing something that does expand correctly in that context is more difficult. <strike>You can leave it outside the quotes, but that could cause problems if the home directory path includes a space -- which I hope would never actually happen.</strike> *Correction, thanks to Charles Duffy: String splitting is disabled on assignments, so that wouldn't be an issue.*

Comment: As string splitting is disabled on assignments, even the space-in-a-home-directory case would work correctly with the expansion unquoted in the context at hand.